# Inject ads to Google Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a google chrome extension, and planning to inject ads using the allowed feature. I have checked in front of "Ads Behavior" that says "This extension injects ads into some third-party websites."

My question is, how and where do I mention the source of ad? Say, if I want do display google adsense, how do I set it up??

I searched it throughout the day today, but didn't get any information anywhere.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 3):

Injecting ads is not that simple.
The first problem you will face is to find an ad network that allows extensions to inject advertisements in pages. AdSense doesn't allow this behavior.
The second (and maybe more complicated) problem is to inject the ads. In a chrome extension you can use [script injection](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi) to add the advertisements to the pages. The real problem is where to put the advertisements. They should be placed in a smart manner; ensure they don't conflict with the page layout/functionality; they shouldn't be everywhere and on every page, otherwise your users will promptly uninstall the extension; you absolutely shouldn't just replace existing ads if you don't want your extension to be flagged as malware.

I haven't yet added ads to my extension because of these and others problems, and I am striving to get some money from it since it has cost me a considerable amount of time to create it, and I have received very, very few donations considering the over 150.000 users.

Hope I could help.

Comment: Hey @Franceso, are you currently successfully monetizing your extension? Could you share your solution?

Comment: @cprcrack not really. I never went through with ADS injection, and gave up on monetizing the extension, except for donations