# Advertisements on Chrome Extension

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I have made a popular extension but I am trying to put advertisements on there.
Below is my code.

The code works when I put it in a Html Tester. It shows the advertisement. But when I test it as an extension the advertisement does not appear but the game does. Is there a reason?

Is there a way I can fix it?
Thanks

```html
<html>
    <head>

    <body>
      
<script type="text/javascript">
    atOptions = {
        'key' : '158047a6e4d1f2e9957e2ce46ec501a4',
        'format' : 'iframe',
        'height' : 90,
        'width' : 728,
        'params' : {}
    };
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://extractplayed.com/158047a6e4d1f2e9957e2ce46ec501a4/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>
  



<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   
               <form action="https://stackoverflow.com/" method="get" class="inline" target="myiframe">
         <button type="submit">testing</button>
        </form>
        <iframe name="myiframe" height="545" width="750"></iframe>
        
               
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just want to mention the [Single Purpose Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/single_purpose/#thirteen) which would prevent you from doing this if it isn't the only purpose of your extension.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inject ads to Google Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209290/inject-ads-to-google-chrome-extension)

Comment: @Weetz It doesn't, injecting is using an extension to put ads on a website but I want an advertisement in the extension.

Comment: I'm putting advertisements on the extension popup, not injecting the advertisement on a website.

Comment: I would still consider it more than a single purpose extension if it's in the popup. I've not seen any successful extension that has been able to get it approved.

Comment: The main purpose is for people to play games on it. But I want to put an advertisement on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

In Manifest V3, all of your extension's logic must be bundled with the extension. You can no longer load and execute a remotely hosted file.

Comment: So if I change it to Manifest V2 it will work? Because the extension works fine itself but its just the advertisement that doesn't appear. When I test the Html code by itself it works but when I test it as an extension it can't.

Comment: As of January 17, 2022 Chrome Web Store stops accepting new Manifest V2 extensions with visibility set to “Public" or "Unlisted”. Existing Manifest V2 extensions can no longer be changed from “Private” to "Public" or "Unlisted".

Comment: Is an embed a remotley hosted file?